# iTextSharp writes strings in different font size than one that is manually inputed

Tags: c#, itext

I am using the iTextSharp to read existing pdf file and populate its fields. In pdf, all fields font sizes are set to Auto. This is important to me and I don't want to change this option bacause there is no characters limit in input form fields.

For some reason, pdf fields content is generated in too small font size.
[image: field_filled_out_with_itextsharp]

When I manually try to fill in the fields in pdf, font size is normal (as the field's height).
[image: manually_filled_out_field]

This is the code that I am using when reading and writing the file.

```
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(String.Format("{0}\\document.pdf", ApplicationSettings.DocumentsFolder));
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output) { FormFlattening = true };
    AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

    fields.SetField(nameof(document.LicenseeName), "LicenseePrintName");

    pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;

    pdfStamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
```

Is anyone encountered this problem and how to resolve it? I tried to set the textsize of field to 0 and 0f (this should be Auto size) and problem still occurs.